# emailing users in user reference field with rules

Tags: 7, users, rules

I am working on a site for an academic conference. Right now, we have two content types (1) proposal and (2) peer review. In the proposal content type, an author can add multiple presenters to a user reference field. When the node is saved, I have a rule that loops through the user reference field and sends an email notification to all the presenters that the proposal has been submitted. Works great!

Now the question. I want to send an email to that same group of users when someone else posts a peer review. I have figured out how to notify the "author" of the proposal but I want to notify all the users listed in the node reference field.

Right now my rule is set up as follows:
Event: after saving new content
Conditions: content is of type > peer review
Actions: Fetch entity by property:
-Value: node
-Value: node reference
-Data selector: node
Variable label: Fetched proposal
Variable name: fetched_proposal

Then I have a loop:
Data selector: fetched-proposal
Current list item
Variable label: Current proposal item
Variable name: proposal_list_item

Then I have an action to send the mail. Since I've looped over the proposal connected to the peer review, I have available a token for the presenter field which contains the node reference. I've used that token in the "To" value field.

I think this should work but I don't get emails when testing.

When I check my log messages I see this error: The loop Loop () fails the integrity check and cannot be executed. Error: Data selector fetched-proposal: for parameter list is invalid.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are fetching the user reference wrongly. You should try this:

- On the Action:Fetch Entity by ID
- Value:User
- Data selector :node:field-name:uid (this is your user reference field
- Variable label:Fetched entity
- Variable name :user_entity

Then you are good to go!